# Manipulating textInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, text, shiny, textinput

I am relatively new to R and even more new to Shiny (literally first day).

I would like a user to input multiple phrases separated by a comma such as `female, aged, diabetes mellitus.` I have a dataframe in which one variable, `MH2` contains text words. I would like to output a dataframe that contains only the rows in which all of the inputted phrases are present. Sometimes a user may input only one phrase, other times 5.

This is my ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

# load dataset
load(file = "./data/all_cardiovascular_case_reports.Rdata")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "phrases", 
                label = "Please enter all the MeSH terms that you would like to search, each separated by a comma:",
                value = ""),

      helpText("Example: female, aged, diabetes mellitus")

    ),
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("dataframe"))
  )
)
```

and here is my server.R

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  # where all the code will go
    df <- reactive({

      # counts how many phrases there are
      num_phrases <- str_count(input$phrases, pattern = ", ") + 1

      a <- numeric(num_phrases) # initialize vector to hold all phrases

      # create vector of all entered phrases
      for (i in 1:num_phrases)
      {
        a[i] <- noquote(strsplit(input$phrases, ", ")[[i]][1])
      }

      # make all phrases lowercase
      a <- tolower(a)

      # do exact case match so that each phrase is bound by "\\b"
      a <- paste0("\\b", a, sep = "")
      exact <- "\\b"
      a <- paste0(a, exact, sep = "")

      # subset dataframe over and over again until all phrases used
      for (i in 1:num_phrases)
      {
        final <- final[grepl(pattern = a, x = final$MH2, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
      }

      return(final)
    })

    output$dataframe <- DT::renderDataTable({df()})
}
```

When I tried running `renderText({num_phrases})` I consistently got `1` even when I would input multiple phrases separated by commas. Since then, whenever I try to input multiple phrases, I run into "error: subscript out of bounds." However, when I enter the words separated by a comma only versus a comma and space (entering "female,aged" instead of "female, aged") then that problem disappears, but my dataframe doesn't subset correctly. It can only subset one phrase.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Shiny logic looks good, but the function for subsetting the dataframe has a few small issues. In particular:

`a[i] <- noquote(strsplit(input$phrases, ", ")[[i]][1])`

The indices `[[i]]` and `1` are in the wrong place here, should be `[[1]][i]`

```
final <- final[grepl(pattern = a, x = final$MH2, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
```

You can not match multiple patterns like this, only the first element of a will be used, which is also the warning R gives.

---

**Example working code**

I have changed `input$phrases` to `inp_phrases` here. If this script does what you want I think you can easily copy it into you reactive, making the necessary changes (i.e. changing `inp_phrases` back, and adding the `return(result)` statement.). I was also not entirely clear if you wanted all patterns to be matched within one row, or return all rows were any of the patterns were matched, so I added them both, you can uncomment the one you need:

```
library(stringr)

# some example data
inp_phrases = "ab, cd"
final = data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4),MH2 = c("ab cd ef","ab ef","cd ef ab","ef gx"),stringsAsFactors = F)

# this could become just two lines:
a <- sapply(strsplit(inp_phrases, ", ")[[1]],  function(x) tolower(noquote(x)))
a <- paste0("\\b", a, "\\b") 

# Two options here, uncomment the one you need.
# Top one: match any pattern in a. Bottom: match all patterns in a
# indices = grepl(pattern = paste(a,collapse="|"), x = final$MH2, ignore.case = TRUE)
indices = colSums(do.call(rbind,lapply(a, function(x) grepl(pattern = x, x = final$MH2, ignore.case = TRUE))))==length(a)

result <- final[indices,]
```

Returns:

```
  index      MH2
1     1 ab cd ef
3     3 cd ef ab
```

... with the second version of indices (match all) or

```
  index      MH2
1     1 ab cd ef
2     2    ab ef
3     3 cd ef ab
```

... with the first version of indices (match any)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I used the code that matches all of the phrases. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!